# Files are not attached to my Nuget Package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I wanna create a very simple Nuet package.I just want to add a file(Such as image,Text Files,..) and when i install this test package, the attached files get added into my solution.I did the below steps :

1 : i created a custom Nuget Server (IIS).
2: I used the Nuget.exe command to create the package, create folder and copy the desired files into the folder

```
> NuGet Pack YourPackageName.nuspec
> mkdir content
> copy ..\src\SomeController.cs content
```

3: i Copied content Folder" and created package (YourPackageName.nuspec) into my package folder of Local nuget server (IIS Website)

Now, when i connect to local nuget server, i can see the package(YourPackageName.nuspec) and install it on my project BUT the "content" Folder, is not added to my Project.

Can anyone helps me?! What am i supposed to do more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your nuspec file, did you specify something like below:

```
<file src="..\src\SomeController.cs" target="content\SomeController.cs" />
```

Please refer to this link http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference for more details, there is a section called "Specifying Files to Include in the Package" that should provide insights.